# Windows Forms c# picturebox and whitespace

Tags: c#, winforms, image, panel, picturebox

I have been designing a simple powerpoint/image-editor style program.

I have a panel in my program where I can drag and drop in multiple images and textboxes, resize and move these items.

The problem I am having is that I want to be able to place multiple images on the panel and these may overlap, so at the minute I get all the excess whitespace because of the picturebox even when the png or bitmap has no whitespace, its the filler whitespace between the image and the picturebox.

Hope that makes sense

I have posted an image which shows the problem.

[image]

Can anyone see a solution to this problem?

Comment: Is your Image type of `GIF` or `PNG` which supports transparent color so that only the image is displayed without background around?

Comment: If you are doing custom drawing and multiple images then I would recommend using a `Panel` rather than a `PictureBox`

Comment: Hi Both. King King, I am using PNGs so if I was to put the above images into paint.net for example, they would have transparent backgrounds and no white space. musefan, so just use panels and set the background image?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to override the `OnPaintBackground`-method, as shown here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8689454/2549398

Comment: Hi, I will give this a try. I take it I would implement these override methods on the panel on which I am dragging the pictireboxes onto?

Comment: Sorry, was busy yesterday. Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: Hi, I haven't yet as yesterday I started playing about with WPF, but trying to translate what I have already done in WinForms to WPF has proved troublesome. So I am going to go back to my WinForms and try what you have suggested. So I have a UserControl which consists of a picturebox and has several event handlers attached to do various things. Do I override the onPaint etc for this user control? As I am working with a bitmap in the picturebox which is added to the picturebox by picturebox.image what do I do where it says //Do your drawing here

Comment: Having added the code suggested to my custom picturebox class what was whitespace is now solid black ?? :-S