# C# transparent PictureBox

Tags: c#, transparency, picturebox

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688295/how-to-make-a-picturebox-truly-transparent) solution, but got "Invalid window handle" message.

Without

```
protected override void OnMove(EventArgs e)
{
    RecreateHandle(); //-- seems to be a problem
}
```

form is working, but pictureBox is without transparency.

What should I do?

Comment: Well, it's quite a bad idea to destroy a window while it is being moved.  PictureBox already supports transparency [pretty well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5523359/17034).

Comment: For immobilized sure, but not for moving pictureBox. PictureBox's transperacy is a layer created by parent image (so it's a camouflage). When pictureBox is moving, it's creating a new layer. Unfortunately, creating uncurrectly (picture is not maching with the original). Try to create a background layer (on form or another pictureBox) and a pictureBox with transparent .png (with png.BackColor = Color.Transparent and png.Parent = background_layer); make png move with timer (10 ms) and see how it works. That is why I'm looking for a solution to make pictureBox truly transperant.

Comment: The probable intention in that code was to just get the window to repaint.  RecreateHandle does that but is the atom bomb approach.  Use Invalidate() instead.